# Send Push Notification to mobile whiteout APNS or GCM

Tags: android, ios, websocket, push-notification, signalr

I have a question about Push Notification.

I have private service that it must send to mobile app (`iOS,Android`) push notification. I send notification through `ID connection`, not through `ID device`. I used `Signal R` connection (type of web socket). Is it possible?
Will Apple and Google accept this compromise?

PS: My app is an Enterprise App, it is only for my client, not for All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not sending notifications without apns. Its strictly restricted by apple.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html